# Sculpt tool will not work on mesh

Tags: sculpting

Attached is the picture of the tree I am currently making from a tutorial. I am trying to sculpt the icospheres, however the sculpt tool does absolutely nothing to them. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The icospheres were not duplicated while in edit mode before trying to sculpt.